# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" visual studio when hitting enter

Tags: visual-studio-2013

For some reason, every time I hit enter in Visual Studio 2013, I get a message saying “Object reference not set to an instance of an object”
Why?
It's really annoying and I can't work like this.

Thanks,
-Gie

Comment: I've had the same issue, for me it was some addon/extension that messed up, so you could try disabling or removing extensions.

Answer (score 1):

To verify if it's an extension at fault here, try running VS from the VS command prompt with the /safemode switch:

devenv /safemode

This will keep the IDE from loading any extensions, and if the problem disappears you've found your culprit. Though you'll likely have to narrow it down with some experimentation, but disabling suspect extensions from the Extension Gallery dialog.

Comment: I never installed any extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I have been having this problem for while and this seem to have fixed it.

Open in your preferred editor: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config`

Search for `</DbProviderFactories>` and make sure there is no extra tag left behind. For me it i had an extra close (`</DbProviderFactories>`) tag. I removed that and it work perfectly.

And do same with this file `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config`

Hope this helps.

Thanks