# Xamarin Android Project

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

Using Xamarin in VS2013 Pro.  The starter package.  Whenever I start an android project it starts out with two errors:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

The file and project are blank, the line and column are 0.  And when I double click the error nothing happens.  How can I fix this?  I haven't had a chance to test iOS yes as I do not have a mac, but I've found others with the issue and no one had a solution.  I've also never seen those fields blank before, or noticed it that is.  And I'm not sure what that means.  Making debugging near impossible for me.

By the way, I'm using the Blank Application Android template.  As per their tutorials.  Although this obviously affects more than tutorials as I cannot even start an app.  I have confirmed the problem also exists with the other Android templates as well.

Any help is much appreciated, even small bits of information may help me find the answer.  As the platform being relatively new lacks a large base of information on usage with Visual Studio.  I will test Xamarin Studio and report back once it finishes installing (although the whole point is to stick with VS) but I heard people had the problem with both.

Thank you for you time.

EDIT:  The problem does not exist in Xamarin Studio.  Only VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the same messages, but they don't prevent me from actually building my project. I used to see a bunch of them, following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24462449/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-visual-studio-when-hittin/24829767#24829767) I was able to get rid of them.